# Do some Zope 3 resources take parameters from the URL?

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity

In Plone 4, I have a custom Dexterity content type that has a NamedBlobFile field called audio_artifact. When using the default edit view to edit the type, I see URLs like this:

[image]

What's going on here? I'm familiar with Zope 3 resources in general, but here it looks the widget resource is being passed the @@download view as a parameter. Is that correct? Or am I just confused. I suspect the latter.

Comment: I think that's widget traversing syntax - widgets need to be traversable, so that e.g. image widget can show the thumbnail. This was huge pain in the ass when I created imageportlet package where portlets require special traversal mechanisms.

Comment: Is that the `crackles.ogg` link under the `Audio Artifact` field? That's just the best way to download that file without the widget having to know about how your dexterity object *or* the schema field would handle the download.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, sorry, I'll fix the picture.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And I don't understand the rest of your comment, can you explain more? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`++something++` is a traversal namespace, so it's not a resource per se, `++resource++` is instead another namespace. Namespaces look up custom namespace handlers, which are given the rest of the item name.

In this case the `widget` namespace handler is given the name of the widget, `forms.widgets.audio_artifact`, and it will use this to look up that widget on the add form.

`@@download` is a view on the widget, that enables you to download the file in the widget. For images there is also a view that allows you to get thumbnails etc.

Comment: Ahhh, OK I was completely missing the "traversal namespace" aspect, will read up on that thanks

Comment: And, while ++resource++ is resource-ish, this sort of traversal trick is very generally useful. A nice talk: http://www.uwosh.edu/ploneprojects/docs/presentations/plone-symposium-east-2012-slides/Traversing%20Plone.pdf

Comment: Thanks @SteveM! That is indeed a very nice presentation.

Answer (score 4):

++widget++form.widgets.audio_artifact traverses to a widget on the @@edit form, and then @@download is a view of that widget.